# Why does my array read from file contain bytes

Tags: arrays, ruby, file

I'm writing a little system that parses lines of data in a txt separated by commas,
so to be basic about it I read the file lines into an array, then use .each on the array and split everything by "'" then push it into the holding array which is returned as the database made from the file, I have made two, the first works fine but its data is stored line by line with a keyword, this one works fine, access and return all good.

I'm using a file containing text data like this

---

```
476,TACKLE,40,25,30,0,0,1,A3F,move description string with, punctuation and t's
477,ANOTHERATTACK,BLAHBLAHBLAH,1,2,3,4
```

---

This would be data parsing kind of right, well

so I go:

---

```
$fs  = File_SYstem.new
@path = Dir.getwd.to_S + "/desktop/file.txt"
@data_lines = $fs.file_read_lines(@path)
@data = []
@data_lines.each do |line|
  @data >> line.split(',')
end
return @data
#this would make an array of the lines, each line being an array of its elements, right?

@data = The_Code_Above_In_A_Class.new(@path)
=>@data

@data[0]
=>"354,FISSURE,10,40,50,blah blah blah, the second half of the text."

#hmmmm

@data[0][0]
=>"354"
```

So it seems to work fine, but some times, the numbers at the beginning come back as bytes :O

And for example:

```
@data.each do |line|
  puts line[1].to_S #return second element which is name of move
end
```

This would print a list of the expected names, fine and dandy, but then I get the remaining data I didn't ask for returned below it in an unrecognizable pattern.

Maybe I can do this?

```
array = [1,2,3]
array = [array,array,array]
array[2][0] = "Hello!"
array.each do |item|
  puts item[2]
end
 =>"3"
"3"
"Hello!"
=>:
```

---

Seems to me this should work since I'm already using close variations of this style somewhere else with success.

Now this is a sample of the real 580 line file:

---

```
1,MEGAHORN,Megahorn,000,120,BUG,Physical,85,10,0,00,0,abef,Cool,"Using its tough and  impressive horn, the user rams into the target with no letup."
2,ATTACKORDER,Attack Order,000,90,BUG,Physical,100,15,0,00,0,befh,Smart,The user calls out its underlings to pummel the target. Critical hits land more easily.
3,BUGBUZZ,Bug Buzz,046,90,BUG,Special,100,10,10,00,0,bek,Cute,The user vibrates its wings to generate a damaging sound wave. It may also lower the target's Sp. Def stat.
```

---

Now this is the class I use to load it up:

```
class Move_Data_Extracter
  def initialize(path)
        load $path.to_s + "/source/string_helper.rb"
    #load "/mnt/sdcard/pokemon/system/source/string_helper.rb"
        @path = path.to_s
    @file_lines = $file_system.file_read_lines(@path.to_s)
    $movedata = []
    @file_lines.each do |line|
      $movedata << line.split(",")
    end
  end
  def get_move_id(move_name)
    $movedata.each do |move|
      if move[1].upcase.to_s == move_name.upcase.to_s
            return move[0].to_i
      else
        return "Move Doesnt Exist In The System!"
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

---

This is the feedback I got when I accessing the first item in the returned array(s?):

---

```
irb(main):002:0> $movedata[0]
=> ["\xEF\xBB\xBF1", "MEGAHORN", "Megahorn", "000", "120", "BUG", "Physical", "8
5", "10", "0", "00", "0", "abef", "Cool", "\"Using its tough and impressive horn
", " the user rams into the target with no letup.\"\n"]
irb(main):003:0> $movedata[0][0]
=> "\xEF\xBB\xBF1"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Access worked ok this time but the first element is bytes and that each method I'm trying is going so wrong.

Can anyone figure out whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, that's obviously not the code you're using as things like `to_S` aren't part of ruby and would instantly fail anyway.

Let's clean up the code a bit:

```
# $fs  = File_SYstem.new # this is just not needed
path = File.expand_path "/desktop/file.txt" # instance variables *only* within explicit objects
data_lines = File.read( path ).split ","
```

I've no idea what the rest of what you've written really means.

This outputs:

```
# => ["476", "TACKLE", "40", "25", "30", "0", "0", "1", "A3F", "move description string with", " punctuation and t's\n477", "ANOTHERATTACK", "BLAHBLAHBLAH", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

This bit of code - what is it?

```
array = [1,2,3]
array = [array,array,array] # pure craziness!
array[2][0] = "Hello!"
array.each do |item|
  puts item[2]
end
 =>"3"
"3"
"Hello!"
=>:
```

As to why you're getting back bytes, it's because the file is (likely) encoded as UTF-8. Try `File.read( path, "r:UTF-8")` to get Ruby to use the correct encoding.

Comment: thanks for being a critical retard you know what i meant, thanks for helping with the bytes though

Comment: @JakeSlone read the FAQ - rudeness is not tolerated. No, I don't know what you meant, and if you do then you need to think again about your code. Hard. I've flagged you because using the word "retard" is disgusting, and you should think even harder about that.